# should i use redis like this : req.session.surname = 'toto' or like this client.set('surname', 'toto')

Tags: node.js, express, redis, redis-server

whats up! I am using redis with express and nodejs. when looking how to insert or retrieve data from redis, I saw two ways, one like this:

```
req.session.surname = 'toto'
console.log(req.session.surname)
```

and the other way is looking like this:

```
client.set('surname', 'toto')
client.get('surname', (err, data) => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

Is there a difference between these two methods ?
Thanks for any help. Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no major difference between these two methods. In the first one you could use any other session store like `mongo-db` if you need more reliability (since `redis` is `memcached` there is a possibility to lose the data as data will be stored in RAM only). Second one is just **set and get** the desired value to the key for general usage where there is no 100% reliability is needed. Also you will face issue when processing request concurrently as there is no concurrency control for mem-cached DB like redis.

If you need **100% reliability** (if you don't want to lose data easily) you can go with `mongo-db`. In **mongo-db** data will be stored persistently also we can control concurrency as well.